# Boost Intrusive unordered_set static member function returns wrong size type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-intrusive

Consider this code, which compiles successfully:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

typedef unordered_set_member_hook<> Hook;

struct Item
{
    Hook hook;
};

typedef unordered_set<Item,
    member_hook<Item, Hook, &Item::hook>,
    size_type<uint32_t> > Map;

static_assert(4 == sizeof(typename Map::size_type));
static_assert(8 == sizeof(decltype(Map::suggested_upper_bucket_count(1000))));
```

In both [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/unordered_set.html) and [the code](https://github.com/boostorg/intrusive/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp#L375), `suggested_upper_bucket_count()` is declared this way:

```
static size_type suggested_upper_bucket_count(size_type);
```

So how can it be that `Map::size_type` is 4 bytes (`uint32_t`) yet the result of `suggested_upper_bucket_count()` is 8 bytes?

See it live: https://godbolt.org/g/3Sz8Xj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that's fixed in Boost 1.65

- Wandbox w/1.64.0 https://wandbox.org/permlink/bATVUkq5T0N5oCR4
- Wandbox w/1.65.0 https://wandbox.org/permlink/YFuIysXJCS1u3x9E

Comment: Thanks for that.  It looks like the bug was introduced in 1.59; earlier versions don't seem afflicted.  Can you tell me where the bug actually is?  It is quite mysterious to me after looking at the code.  I found this ticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/12894 but it seems aimed at fixing some possibly related but different problem.  What I don't understand is how `size_type` is `uint32_t` yet this function which returns `size_type` returns `uint64_t`.  Surely there is some dark magic here.

Comment: No, I've mainly just compared the behaviour (because it just worked with 1.65 for me, I was lucky). I had briefly looked at changelogs (non-existent) and commit history but with not immediate suspect.